# http://localhost:4200/api/auth.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular

app.module.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class AuthService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getUserDetails(username, password){ return this.http.post('/api/auth.php',{ username, password }).subscribe(data => { console.log(data, "Is what we got from the server"); }) } }
```

proxyconfig.json

```
{ "/api": { "target": "http://localhost/test/api/auth.php", "secure": false, "changeOrigin": true

}
}
```

Comment: your code is **unreadable**

Comment: though, the only URL I can see is `"target": "http://localhost:80/test/api/auth.php"` - but your error message refers to `http://localhost:4200/api/auth.php` ... is the code in the question at all related to the error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My angularjs application running on 4200 port . But php is running on Another  server port . I want to authenticate user with auth.php.But i am not able to make request to that file from npm server

Comment: I am referring https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKzyDg-Ll18&index=16&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlqCmHqDyW3yo5V79C7eaTe   this  tutorial

Comment: Post your auth.php  code, and also what do you get from your console.log? How can we help you if you don't provide such a basic informations?

Answer (score 0):

I was following this tutorial and had the same issue, I had to add this code to the start of auth.php file;

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");
```

So first five lines now look like;

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");
session_start();
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```